# How object has created in java?

Tags: java

Question : Object is created in Java using constructor and as we know there is no return type of constructor .Now how the Object reference is pointing to that object address ?

Example :

```
Class Demo{

    private String objName;

    Demo(String objName){
        this.objName = objName; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo obj1 =  new Demo("first"); 
    }

}
```

In the example we have object `obj1`, how object reference getting the Object address inernally?

Comment: References `obj1` and `obj2` are kept in the *stack*, while their referenced object are found on the *heap*. What more do you need to know? A quick Google Search would answer your question instantly.

Comment: All this magic is because of `new` keyword.. Not by `constructor`. Constructor does not have return type but `new` have

Comment: it gets two different reference beacause a contractor method create a nex instance

Comment: He tricked you bro, there is a new operator which will take care of that.

Comment: @Kiwy No. A *constructor* ***initializes*** a new instance. The instance is *created* by the 'new' operator.

Comment: @EJP thanks for the correction, it's been a while since I leave java developement.

Comment: @Kiwy It's the same in C++ or any other comparable OO language.

Comment: "how both object getting different reference inernally?" Because that's what `new` does? Your question is basically asking: "I created two objects. Why do I have two objects?"

Answer (score 2):

Why shouldn't they? You call the new Operator that reserve Memory into Heap. So it is natural that you get two different references for obj1 and obj2. As far as i know, by doing

```
this.objName = objName;
```

You copy the content of objName to this.objName because String in Java are copied and not just linked.

Answer (score 0):

When `new` operator is encountered new instance of the corresponding class is created in the Heap. And the address of the same(reference) is stored on the stack.